# how to combine 2 models to realize permissions system

Tags: python, django, django-models

I am designing pet project for communities news system. I have this models: User, Group, Post, Like. I want to allow each User to Like posts. In addition to this some Users can be managers of Groups (like manyToMany relation), so they will be able to edit Group information and create Posts from Group name. But one of this "group managers" will have role "shef", and will be able to add/remove managers from his group. "shef" can be added just in Django Admin.

What is the best way to design User <-> Group relation? I thought about Group having manyToMany to User (managers) and foreignKey to "shef", will it be optimal solution? How should I design the project to follow best practices, or should I use 3rd party libraries like django-guardians in this situation?

Comment: Django already has groups for the builtin user model and permissions.